# How to initialize the array member with constant member value?

Tags: c++, arrays, class, initialization, constants

I want to use a constant value to initialize member array.

--Test.h--

```
class Test {
public:
  static int ARRAY_SIZE;
...
..
private
  int m_array[ARRAY_SIZE];
}
```

--Test.cpp--

```
int Test::ARRAY_SIZE = 20;
```

But, it shows error like this.
'array bound is not an integer constant before ‘]’'

So, I want to know there is a solution for this.

I want fixed size of array. and i don't want any dependency
(like additional files for constant value)

What is the best practice for this?

Comment: Have you tried: `static const int ARRAY_SIZE;` and `const int Test::ARRAY_SIZE = 20;` ?

Comment: It works, but when i use int m_array[ARRAY_SIZE]
it shows same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is correct. Your array bound is a variable, not a constant.

```
static int ARRAY_SIZE;
```

The above declares a variable. The below declares a constant.

```
static const int ARRAY_SIZE;
```

For an array's size, there is an additional requirement beyond simply being declared `const`: the size must be initialized with a constant expression, also known as a compile-time constant (a constant value known by the compiler). If a translation unit sees the declaration of `ARRAY_SIZE` but does not see its value, then it does not count as a compile-time constant. To remedy this, the initialization needs to be in the header file. Combine initialization with declaration:

```
static const int ARRAY_SIZE = 20;
```

Since C++11, there has been a fancy way to express that you have a compile-time constant, which you might want to get into the habit of using when it applies:

```
static constexpr int ARRAY_SIZE = 20;
```

Comment: Thanks, I apply like this 'static const int ARRAY_SIZE = 20' in test.h file.

But i have one more question.

When i try to initialize in test.cpp, it shows same error.
test.h
static const int ARRAY_SIZE;
test.cpp
const int ARRAY_SIZE = 20;

Comment: @Siimson My bad, that was a shortcoming of my answer. I've added the missing info.